# How to use inbuilt bluetooth in win xp and win vista?

Tags: command-line, windows-vista

By typing `fsquirt` in run command, a Bluetooth file transfer wizard opens.  If we click next and select either of them it won`t work.  How does it works and how to connect the bluetooth to different computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883259)

When you install a supported Bluetooth adapter in Windows XP SP2, the adapter becomes active together with the following Microsoft components:

- Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator
  This component enumerates Bluetooth devices and capabilities.
- Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  This driver supports Personal Area Network (PAN) connections between devices.
- Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol Transport Driver Interface [TDI])
  This component supports dial-up networking (DUN). It also supports other types of connections between devices.
- Bluetooth Support Service (BthServ)
  This service maintains and updates device pairing information. It also performs other functions that are related to Bluetooth features.

These components are available in Device Manager after you install a Bluetooth adapter. Other drivers and components are also installed.

> The Options tab in Bluetooth Devices provides options that control how devices discover and connect to your computer. The main option is Turn discovery on. This option lets devices discover your computer so that you can make a connection.

Other options on this tab include the following:

- Allow Bluetooth devices to connect to this computer
  This check box controls whether any devices can connect to your computer. If this check box is cleared, no devices can connect to your computer.
- Alert me when a new Bluetooth device wants to connect
  This option controls whether you receive notification when a device tries to connect to your computer. If this check box is cleared, you do not receive notification.

Other options on the Options tab let you turn on or turn off the Bluetooth icon in the notification area and restore default settings.